# Let $X$ be an ordered set in the order topology. Under what condition the equality $Cl(a,b) = [a,b]$ holds?

Tags: general-topology

In the book of *General Topology* by Munkress, at page 100, question 5, it is asked that

> Let $X$ be an ordered set in the order topology. Show that $Cl(a,b)
>  \subseteq [a,b]$. Under what condition the equality holds ?

I have proved that first part, and for why the inequality does not hold, I gave the following argument:

Consider $x=a$, then if there exist $c \in [a,b]$ such that $a<c$ and there is not other element between $a$ and $c$, then we have $(-\infty, c)\cap ([a,b]-\{a\}) = \emptyset$, hence by our previous statement in the theorem, $(-\infty, c)\cap ((a,b)'-\{a\}) = \emptyset$, and since $a\not \in (a,b)$, we have $a \not \in Cl(a,b).$

Therefore, the inequality hold iff $X$ is dense, hence for any $a,c \in X$, there are infinitely many elements between $a$ and $c$ in $X$.

So, **is my argument correct ? or is there any problem with it ?**

**Edit:**
I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134470/munkres-topology-question-article-17-problem-5) answer after I have posted my question, but in there the answer giving as $a$ not having any left neighborhood, which is different from my answer.

Comment: If $a<b$ then $\overline {(a,b)}=[a,b]$  iff $(\;a=\inf \{x:x>a\}$ and $b=\sup \{y:y<b\;).$

Comment: Dense is too strong of a condition.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet.  In order theory terms iff a is not covered and b is not a cover.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I do not understand what you trying to say, could you elaborate, please ?

Comment: For any $u\in X$ let $(u,\to)$ denote $\{v:v>u\} $ and let $[u,\to)$ denote $\{v:v\ge u\}$  (regardless of whether or not $X$ has a largest member)......For $a<b$ the set $(a,\to)$ is not empty (because it contains $b$), and $a$ is a lower bound for $(a,\to).$.... Now  if $a \ne \inf  (a,\to)$ then there is a  lower bound $c$ for $(a,\to)$  with $c>a.$ Then $c$ is also a lower bound for $(a,b)$ because $(a,b)\subset (a,\to). $ ..... So, since $a<c ,$ we have  $a\not \in [c,\to) =$ $\overline { [c,\to)}  \supset $ $\overline {(a,b)},$  so $a \not \in \overline {(a,b)}.$

Comment: @bof I is just a typo about the formatting, I corrected now.

Comment: Is the question asking what conditions the given elements $a$ and $b$ must satisfy in order for $\operatorname{Cl}(a,b)=[a,b]$ to hold, or is it asking what conditions the ordered set $X$ must satisfy in order for $\operatorname{Cl}(a,b)=[a,b]$ to hold for *all* $a$ and $b?$

Comment: @bof I have just copied the question from the book directly, so there was no specification about that, but still we can assume both cases. I mean we can consider first for the element, and then for the set.